# Using parent prop on child function

Tags: vue.js

please help me understand what I'm doing wrong here:

I have a child component that receives a prop from its parent. I want to extract part the first character of that prop value inside the child component, but I'm getting an "undefined" error. Here's the code:

**Parent Component:**

Child Component:

```
<template>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>{{ label }}</label>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input
        class="form-check-input"
        type="text"
        id="inputAgno"
        v-model="aaaa"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  props: ["label", "value"],
  computed:{
    aaaa: function() {
        return this.alta_establecimiento.subStr(0,4)
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is the this.documentNumber defined??

Comment: My mistake, just corrected that part on the code above.

Comment: Share more of the code please.